# How does passing a Function as parameter works under the hood?

Tags: flutter, dart

*Somewhat Minimal example:*

```dart
void main() {
  A hey = A('hi');
  B yo = B(5);
  yo.cloner(hey.nameModifier);
  hey.nameGetter();
}

class A {
  String _name;
  
  A(this._name);
  
  void nameModifier() {
    _name += " there!";
  }
  
  void nameGetter() {
    print(_name);
  }
}

class B {
  final int _foo;
  
  B(this._foo);
  
  void cloner(Function x) {
    print(_foo);
    x();
  }
}
```

This code works.

I'm curious about the low-level things going on here.

My question:
Passing a function as an argument is probably not like copying the function's body, and pasting it to the destination.

for example, it is probably **NOT** working like this under the hood when `hey.nameModifier` is supplied to `cloner` as an argument:

```dart
void cloner() {
  print(_foo);
  _name += " there!";
}
```

Because `_name` won't be defined under the scope of class `B`, and furthermore, it is a  private field of `A`.
So, I guess, the context of the function and the objects it is accessing (*nameModifier*) are also somehow passed as references to the other function (*cloner*)

P.S.
If the function I was passing was not modifying some internal information like `_name,` but instead performing a simple print, like `print("hello world")`, I wouldn't be confused. Because `print` is defined everywhere.

**The question is not** *how to pass functions as arguments?*, **but** *how come internal information is being dereferenced in this process?*.

Comment: See: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-closures

Comment: If language implementation interests you, you'd probably enjoy Crafting Interpreters by Robert Nystrom: https://craftinginterpreters.com/. It gives a lot of insight into how these sorts of language features are implemented. Incidentally, Robert Nystrom is a prominent member of the Dart language team.

Comment: You're passing [a `Function` object](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Function-class.html).  It's equivalent to passing any object that provides a [`call()` method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes) except that the compiler creates it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each function is saved in the memory and the name of the function is used as a pointer to the location where the function is saved, think of it as using int*.
when you pass the function you pass the location of the function.

So when you call that function it will run inside the A class and therefore _name will be defined.

Comment: Why are you using a C++ tutorial as a reference for a question about Dart?

Comment: @Quentin you are right I didn't notice it was dart

Comment: doesn't dart use c/c++ in the background, or built upon them? So it made perfect sense to me actually.